# How to detect and highlight duplicate text on the same line notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have these logs that I have to search through constantly and I would like to know if it's possible to highlight duplicate text that is on the same line.

Let me give you an example

```
(CLIENT ID:3319) successfully posted to account (CLIENT ID:1323)
```

Now in my scenario, I am looking through the logs for 3319 to determine when CLIENT ID 3319 has successfully posted to their own ID.

```
(CLIENT ID:3319) successfully posted to account (CLIENT ID:3319)
```

When it does find that the ID duplicates in the second ID box, I want it to highlight and detect it as a duplicate.

Comment: Isn't a regex like `\(CLIENT ID:3319\).*\(CLIENT ID:3319\)` enough? Or `(\(CLIENT ID:3319\)).*\1`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I need to know to incorporate that with this

Comment: What do you mean? Please post the sample string and the input you have.

Comment: `\(CLIENT ID:(CLIENTNAME|3319)\).*\(CLIENT ID:\1\)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How do I incorporate it with this strnig (CLIENTNAME|3319)

Comment: `\([^|]+\|\d+\)` (or, if the string is always on one line use `\([^\r\n|]+\|\d+\)`). If "it doesn't work", please post an exact sample string,say what part of it is constant, and provide an expected output.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide exact input string/text that you have and what you want to match.

Comment: Any news, feedback, comments?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a search if regular expression:

1. Ctrl+F
2. Search Mode: Regular Expression (uncheck all other "Search Mode" Options)
3. Find What: `CLIENT ID:(\d+).*CLIENT ID:\1`
4. Click in FindAll

This will list all lines that start and end with the same CLIENT ID

**NOTE**

If you want to filter only client 3319, replace the search by `CLIENT ID:(3319).*CLIENT ID:\1`
to search only client 3319

Comment: I'm currently using (CLIENTNAME|3319) to search for all the logs with the CLIENT's name and the Client's ID. How can I incorporate your search into this aswell?